# Substring extraction from vector in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to extract substrings from a unstructured text.  For example, assume a vector of country names:

```
countries <- c("United States", "Israel", "Canada")
```

How do I go about passing this vector of character values to extract exact matches from unstructured text.

```
text.df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:5), 
text = c("United States is a match", "Not a match", "Not a match",
         "Israel is a match", "Canada is a match"))
```

In this example, the desired output would be:

```
ID     text
1      United States
4      Israel
5      Canada
```

So far I have been working with `gsub` by where I remove all non-matches and then eliminate then remove rows with empty values.  I have also been working with `str_extract` from the stringr package, but haven't had success getting the arugments for the regular expression correct.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. stringr**

We could first subset the 'text.df' using the  'indx' (formed from collapsing the 'countries' vector) as pattern in 'grep' and then use 'str_extract' the get the pattern elements from the 'text' column, assign that to 'text' column of the subset dataset ('text.df1')

```
library(stringr)
indx <- paste(countries, collapse="|")
text.df1 <- text.df[grep(indx, text.df$text),]
text.df1$text <- str_extract(text.df1$text, indx)
text.df1
#  ID          text
#1  1 United States
#4  4        Israel
#5  5        Canada
```

**2. base R**

Without using any external packages, we can remove the characters other than those found in 'ind'

```
text.df1$text <- unlist(regmatches(text.df1$text, 
                           gregexpr(indx, text.df1$text)))
```

**3. stringi**

We could also use the faster `stri_extract` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
na.omit(within(text.df, text1<- stri_extract(text, regex=indx)))[-2]
#  ID         text1
#1  1 United States
#4  4        Israel
#5  5        Canada
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
##
R>  data.table(text.df)[
    sapply(countries, function(x) grep(x,text),USE.NAMES=F),
    list(ID, text = countries)]
   ID          text
1:  1 United States
2:  4        Israel
3:  5        Canada
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the pattern, `p`, and use `strapply` to extract the match to each component of `text` returning `NA` for each unmatched component.  Finally remove the NA values using `na.omit`.  This is non-destructive (i.e. `text.df` is not modified):

```
library(gsubfn)

p <- paste(countries, collapse = "|")
na.omit(transform(text.df, text = strapply(paste(text), p, empty = NA, simplify = TRUE)))
```

giving:

```
  ID          text
1  1 United States
4  4        Israel
5  5        Canada
```

Using dplyr it could also be written as follows (using `p` from above):

```
library(dplyr)
library(gsubfn)

text.df %>% 
  mutate(text = strapply(paste(text), p, empty = NA, simplify = TRUE)) %>%
  na.omit
```